# Magento and WordPress URL integration

Tags: php, magento, urls, seo

I'm in a bit of a conundrum. I've integrated WordPress into my Magento site, currently by a subdirectory. Check it out: http://vapetropolis.ca. If you go to the "reviews" section, you'll note there's a /wordpress in the URL. Obviously, this sucks for SEO. So, I want to get rid of the /wordpress.

How can I do this?

1. Integrate Magento as a subdirectory into WordPress. This is no good, because now Magento will get a /magento - and Magento is strongly SEO'd for as well.
2. Put WordPress files in the root folder along with the Magento files: I've tried doing this, but it breaks all Magento pages (maybe I'm doing it wrong?)
3. I've tried URL rewrites, but I can't seem to get rid of the /wordpress.

So...how can I integrate WordPress into Magento, without having a subdirectory in the URL messing with my site's SEO?

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to achieve is a good idea at all. Even if you can achieve to have magento and wp at the same directory level (and it's not easy to have this) you'll get all kinds of URL conflicts. Imagine you have a product/category/static page "apples" in magento and now you want to blog about it and add a post with the slug "apples" in wp. One of both will now stop working and you'll have a lot of fun debugging this.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, having a subfolder in your URL for your blog does not cause decreasing in your Google rankings.

And, having /blog/ in your URL is totally logical for you and your users, and SEO is all about logic, semantic and other stuff.

Comment: No no no - I need to get rid of it!